# creating query from other tables that has the ID of the primary table in laravel

Tags: laravel, join

Apology for the title. I'm really not sure how to name the title correctly base from my situation. I'm new in coding that's why I am not familiar with proper terminologies.

below are the tables I am working on right now.

[image]

I am displaying the details from loan_application table. I can able to include the loan_durations and users in my @foreach but I realized I need to include also the SUM of the AMOUNT from loan_interests table and the SUM of AMOUNT from LOAN PENALTIES which gives me an headache because I can't pull them out.

**LOAN APPLICATION MODEL**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class LoanApplication extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id','user_id');
    }

    public function loanDuration()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\LoanDuration', 'id','loan_duration_id');
    }

    public function interest()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LoanInterest','loan_id', 'id');
    }    

    public function penalty()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LoanPenalty','loan_id', 'id');
    }    
}
```

**LOAN INTEREST MODEL**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class LoanInterest extends Model
{
    public function loanInterest()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LoanApplication','loan_id', 'id');
    }    
}
```

**LOAN PENALTY MODEL**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class LoanPenalty extends Model
{
    public function loanPenalties()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LoanApplication','loan_id', 'id');
    }    
}
```

**for my controller**

```
public function collectorMembers($id)
{
    $collectormember = CollectorMember::where('collector_id',$id)->get();

    return view('dashboard.collector-members.collector-borrowers-list', compact('collectormember'));
}
```

This gives this result

[image]

the CollectorMember gets the info on this table

[image]

Can you help me please? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Who is a `collectormember` and what relation is between `collectormember` and `loan_applications`? Why your `loan_application` table's id is integer and `loan_intrestes` table's foreign key is varchar(loan_id)?

Comment: I think mismatched something because in Loan Application and Loan Penalty, in both class you are using belongsTo relation, it will be better to use one or many

Comment: thanks @ab_ for responding.

Comment: thanks also @TanvirAhmed for responding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to accomplish what you're after, but first I think you need to revisit your schema and relationships.

- Foreign key columns should be of the same type as the referenced column. For example `loan_id` on the `loan_interests` should be `int(11)` just like the `id` column on the `loan_applications` table
- I think you may be confusing relationship types. For example a `User` `hasMany` `LoanApplication`s and a `LoanApplication` `belongsTo` a `User`. A `LoanApplication` `hasMany` `LoanPenalty`s and `hasMany` `LoanInterest`s. A `LoanPenalty` and a `LoanInterest` both `belongsTo` a `LoanApplication`
- The `user_id` column on the `loan_penalities` table is redundant because a `LoanPenalty` `belongsTo` a `LoanApplication` and a `LoanApplication` `belongsTo` a `User`
- I'd recommend storing currency amounts in cents and using unsigned integers as the column type (e.g. for `interest_amount`)

Consider the following schema (some columns not shown):
[image]

Then consider the following models with relationships:

```php
class User extends Model {
    public function loanApplications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LoanApplication::class);
    }

    public function collectors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Collector::class);
    }
}

class Collector extends Model {
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}

class LoanApplication extends Model {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function loanDuration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LoanDuration::class);
    }

    public function loanInterests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LoanInterest::class, 'loan_id');
    }

    public function loanPenalties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LoanPenalty::class, 'loan_id');
    }
}

class LoanDuration extends Model {
    public function loanApplications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LoanApplication::class);
    }
}

class LoanInterest extends Model {
    public function loanApplication() {
        return $this->belongsTo(LoanApplication::class, 'loan_id');
    }
}

class LoanPenalty extends Model {
    public function loanApplication()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LoanApplication::class, 'loan_id');
    }
}
```

Then to list all loan applications in a Resource Controller:

```php
class LoanApplicationController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $loan_applications = LoanApplication
                                ::with(['user', 'loanInterests', 'loanPenalties'])
                                ->get();

        $loan_applications = $loan_applications->map(function ($loan_application) {
            $loan_application->loan_penalities_sum = $loan_application->loanPenalties->sum('penalty_amount_cents');
            $loan_application->loan_interests_sum = $loan_application->loanInterests->sum('interest_amount_cents');
            return $loan_application;
        });

        return view('dashboard.loan-applications.index', compact('loan_applications'));
    }
}
```

And in your `dashboard.loan-applications.index` blade template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</td>
        <th>Total Interest</td>
        <th>Total Penalty</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($loan_applications as $loan_application)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$loan_application->user->username}}</td>
            <td>{{$loan_application->loan_interests_sum}}</td>
            <td>{{$loan_application->loan_penalties_sum}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**Note the above example does not include pagination; all resources are loaded at once.**

The above example also assumes there should be a many-to-many relationship between `collectors` and `users`, but I would imagine a `Collector` should be related to the `loan_applications` table, not to a `User`.

Comment: actually the collector and borrower are in the same table. which shown in my last screenshot but I get the idea. Overall This is so amazing!!!  thanks you so much I appreciate this much! I will now try this.